# Sentinel-2 2A Surface Reflectance

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

How do I use google earth engine to extract the spectral values of Sentinel-2 2A data from winter wheat samples?

In the data I obtained, the reflectance of some dates in the blue band is greater than that in the red band.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/sub_areas/tdt_dancheng_sample')
var points=ee.FeatureCollection(table);
var roi=points;
print(points);

//var lists =points.toList(points.size()).zip(array.toList());
var array = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(1, 30, 1));

var lists = points.toList(points.size()).zip(array.toList());

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(lists.map(function(l) {
  return ee.Feature(ee.List(l).get(0)).set('PID', ee.List(l).get(1));
}));
print(features);


Export.table.toDrive({
 collection: features,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  description: 'pointCoordinates'});   // save the lat and lon of point


function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .set({ 'system:time_start': image.get('system:time_start') });
}


var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'];//,,'NDVI


//ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED") Level-1C
//ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED") Level-2A

var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') //_SR_HARMONIZED
                  .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .select(bands); 
                 
print(collection1);
//'COPERNICUS/S2_SR'
//COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED
      // 统计影像的数量
      var count = collection1.size();
      print('Count: ', count);
      // 从影像集合中获取影像时间的范围并且进行打印看看效果
      var range = collection1.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
      print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')));

  // // 在集合中获取影像的属性值
  //     var sunStats = collection1.aggregate_stats('system:time_start');
  //     print('system:time_start: ', sunStats);



var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'];//,,'NDVI


var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

var fill = function(img, ini) {

  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);

  var ft2 = img.sampleRegions({
   collection:features,
//  properties:ee.List(['id']),
   properties:ee.List(['PID', 'Id', 'name','lat', 'lon']), 
  scale:10
  });
  var date = img.date().format();
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)});
  return inift.merge(ft3);
};




// Iterates over the ImageCollection
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(collection1.iterate(fill, ft));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: newft,
  description: 'S2_winter_wheat_points',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: You should provide an executable script - this is missing your points. A link to the EE Code Editor (using the `Get Link` button there) makes it even easier to run your code. As to your question, without running this a guess would be that the cloud masking with QA60 is doing a bad job (it usually does). Perhaps that's why you're seeing strange values? Clouds, haze or cloud shadow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is my code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c51835aa72ae8885eccc30a04c8935b0.

Comment: I also considered the issue of removing cloud functions, but upon inspection, I found that this is not the cause.

Comment: Your `table` asset is not shared.

Comment: Very sorry! Here is:https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/sub_areas/jn_ht_wheat_point

Comment: To share it, go to the `Assets` tab on the left hand side in the code editor and locate `users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/sub_areas/jn_ht_wheat_point`. Click the share button and check `Anyone can read`, assuming it's not sensitive data.

Comment: OK! Thanks! https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/sub_areas/tdt_dancheng_sample

Comment: Compare QA60 (https://code.earthengine.google.com/85317df6f968efc5e02118cae42726b0) with Cloud Score+ (https://code.earthengine.google.com/5502051118c7e5a8605c17f303e554be). I would check the results with the latter cloud masking.

Comment: Thank you for your code! It's great! Compared to my code, it is indeed much better. May I ask which band "cs" is?

Comment: And could you please tell me something about 'GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED' ？Thanks！

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/GOOGLE_CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS_V1_S2_HARMONIZED#description

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have retrieved the data using your method, but there are still some issues. For example, the green reflectance of certain data is lower than the red reflectance. Can you give me your email address? I would like to ask you some questions.